# My father refuses to let me marry a boy because of caste; is "caste" an important part of marriage?

Tags: nikah, sharia, fiqh, caste

I'm a Muslim girl and want to marry a Muslim boy who is following Islam properly. So I spoke with my guardian (الولي), that is my father, and he refused the proposal and does not want to meet his family because of difference in caste, as we are jatt and they are mirza. Is cast an important part in Nikkah?

Comment: Short answer: Cast has no bearing over the permissibility of marriage. It's just a personal choice which should rest upon the intended partners.

Comment: Another short answer: Put together the Answers of Aisha, Sayyid and Yousouf Sultan and you have the right and full answer to your Question! Personally I'd put an answer with an evidence from the Quran higher then one with an evidence from the Sunnah.

Answer (score 10):

**Hadith** *(Reported by Al-Bukhari and Muslim)*

> A woman is married for four reasons: her property, lineage, beauty and
>   religion. You should better marry the religious one otherwise you will
>   lose.

Sister, caste should never become a hindrance for a marriage.

If the boy has been sent as your partner, then you will get married to him. In Sha Allah

Comment: in sha Allah and jazak Allah for your answer.

Answer (score 10):

In Islam everyone is equal so caste has no importance.

There is a hadith:
"An Arab has no superiority over a non-Arab"

If you say that one should not marry of a particular caste then you are saying that you are better than them and that makes you ignorant.

“He will not enter Hellfire who has the weight of a seed of faith in his heart and he will not enter Paradise who has the weight of a seed of arrogance in his heart.”

The first thing we should look for when marrying is how committed the person is to Islam. A good Muslim will help you become a better Muslim and Insha'Allah enter Jannah. Their caste will not help your children learn about their religion.

Answer (score 4):

In Islam, there is NO concept of Casts. In islam, the division is only based on 2 things, believer and unbeliever(kafir). So all believers are equal in islam. any believer can marry any other believer, without anything like this cast system.

Comment: I don't think that all believers are equal in Islam. There is such a thing as piety. The pious man/woman believer is closer to Allah (SWT) than others. Allah (SWT) knows best.

Comment: Brother, they are equal in case of Religion, islam.. equal in a way that none of them come under any type of casts...

Comment: I think what @HaseebRamish is trying to say is that piety is in different levels with Muslims. So, the better the more who is committed to Islam, this is how our judgement should be for.

Comment: It is also not for us to decide who is pious. Allah knows best.

Answer (score 1):

The entire purpose of there being different people, tribes, colors, cultures, casts, families etc... So that we all can know one another and intermingle and worship Allah.

Allah said in Surah al-Hujurat 49:14 =

**O mankind, indeed We have created you from male and female and made you nations and tribes that you may know one another. Indeed, the most noble of you in the sight of Allah is the most righteous of you. Indeed, Allah is Knowing and Acquainted.**

The Prophet himself married with women from other cultures and races and tribes.  All the early Muslims did the same.

To stop people from marrying one another because of being different is haraam and anti-social.

It's a polluted misguided belief that Islam came eradicate.

Comment: I am quite supportive to what you said, just not sure if it is haram to not to marry because of caste, I mean, is there a clear evidence of so?

Comment: I was referring to discrimination.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such kahfu.

In islam, it's clearly mentioned are all equal, created by Adam and Eve (AS).  It's we who created such thoughts and have been living with the thought to get married only for caste.  It means we are denying the Qur'an, Hadith, etc.

Answer (score -5):

If we look Islamic Sharia their is a term"kahfu" means that one should prefer to marry within their own cast after that he can go for other cast but they should be equal in all aspects. History has witnessed marrying in other cast has not standed long time, their are always conflicts as in every cast their are different atmosphere and it is difficult for other cast to make their adjustment.

Comment: There's no such a term in Shari'a maybe in your local custom but not in Islmaic Shari'a!

Comment: @Syed Ahmad Raza, brother please provide where is that term used and for what? As Medi1Saif pointed out there is no such term, even I have never come across such term. Please provide us with a reference, if any, so that even we will be able to learn something new.