# Caste in Islam is it wrong or right with hadith as well

Tags: halal-haram, caste

Assalamu waalaikum, I would like to know if caste is portrayed in islam because I know it's forbidden in Islam but my parents say it isn't and we should follow our culture. Also could I please have some hadiths with it, to back up if they don't believe me. Jazakallah.

Comment: Relevant https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12410/my-father-refuses-to-let-me-marry-a-boy-because-of-caste-is-caste-an-importan

Comment: I created a [tag:caste] tag; there's a few questions on this topic now, and they're quite closely related to one another.

Answer (score 1):

"O mankind! We created you from a single (pair) of a male and a female, and made you into nations and tribes, that ye may know each other. Verily the most honoured of you in the sight of Allah is the most righteous of you. And Allah has full knowledge and is well-acquainted. ~Al- Quran, 49:13

Taqwa is the only things that matters for Allah not the color,tribe or cast

So in my opinion one shouldn't consider anyone less human only bcz of race,cast. To follow culture I think it is ok as long as you abide by the Shariah